# building stretchable Image in interface builder

Tags: iphone, cocoa, interface-builder, uiimage

I am trying to build a stretchable image in interface builder. Is this even possible? I have searched the web and cannot come up with a proper solution. I'd appreciate any answers.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly with "stretchable image"...?

Comment: I meant I am looking for a way to build this in IB. But I guess there's no way.  *menuBgImage=[[UIImage imageNamed:@"pm_menu_bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:5];

Comment: @ilteris can you change the correct answer on this post? It correct answer is now wrong...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With iOS7 you now have the option to use slicing within the Xcode5 xcassets catalogue. Then the stretching will be done for you when you add the sliced image. (see [official documentation](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/deve65bd8d0d))

Answer (score 23):

This can be done in interface builder: http://www.slideshare.net/mystcolor/stretchable-images-in-uiimageview-using-ib-only

[image]

Comment: What about this: I only have an image size 10x10, and I want to use it for an UIView of size 20*20? It seems the only way is that I have to initiate a as large as possible image, in order to shrink it to fit in any smaller frame. That keeps UI not to be broken.

Comment: Here we are discussing a specific type of "stretchable image". This is referring to a raster image which contains fixed-size edges and a variable sized middle. Usually the middle is only one pixel tall or wide. To see what is going on, see this box: https://jsbin.com/morojoqamo/edit?html,css,output and resize the window. The borders look the same but the middle grows and shrinks.

Answer (score 11):

If you mean you already have a stretchable image, you can use the Stretching feature of IB. The X and Y values seem to be the positions for the stretch starting point, relative to the entire width and height of the image, i.e. 0.5 would mean a point in the middle of the image.

Same thing for the Width and Height: sizes for the stretchable area, relative to the image size, i.e. setting it to a value of 1 / imageWidth would mean the stretchable area is 1 pixel wide. The strange thing is 0 also work fine for the blue pill button (could be for convenience reasons?).

Below, view modes are set to "Scale to Fill". The images are stretchable images from  https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor.

[image]

This answer was inspired by http://www.slideshare.net/mystcolor/stretchable-images-in-uiimageview-using-ib-only

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible.

Comment: More specifically: Interface Builder is not an image editor, so you cannot make any kind of image in it. Whatever you want to do with an image, you will need to do in code.

Comment: But this is not about image editing but about constructing stretchable images like you can do in code.

Comment: This would be particularly useful when setting a background image for a UITextField. Without being able to set the leftCapWidth in IB you are forced to set the background image in code.

Comment: This answer is NOT correct. It is possible to do using the "Stretching property" of the view. See the answer by Full Decent.